# Can an unordered_map inside struct in c++ cause memory leak issues?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl

I am declaring a struct in C++ which looks like the following:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int x;
    std::unordered_map<int,int> myMap;
};
```

I then use this structure to a create an STL list with "myStruct" entries.

```
std::list<myStruct>
```

I was wondering if this setup can cause potential memory leaks as I add elements to my list, as well to my unordered_map.

If it can cause memory leaks, what would be a better way to set this up?

TIA!

Comment: The short answer: no, it cannot, by itself. Any memory leaks will only be from additional code you would write, but not from the containers themselves.

Comment: If you're not using `new`, it's pretty hard to have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule-of-thumb is that for every use of the keyword *new*, you will need an accompanying use of the keyword *delete*. You do not appear to be creating your list on the heap, so you should be covered. The STL is pretty resilient in this regard.